# Zend Navigation misbehaving

Tags: zend-framework

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Zend Framework - multiplate navigation blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1743630/zend-framework-multiplate-navigation-blocks)

I wanna give more than one links by using Zend_Navigation in the one page...

for example

like this,

```
 echo $this->navigation()->topmenu(); 
 echo $this->navigation()->menu(); 
 echo $this->navigation()->footermenu();
```

but I couldnt do that ...

When I use like following code just works this one

```
echo $this->navigation()->menu();
```

I use like following codes.

```
 $container = new Zend_Config_Xml(APPLICATION_PATH .'/configs/navigation.xml' 'nav_top');   

 $navigation = new Zend_Navigation($container);
            $view->navigation($navigation);
```

How can I create different links in the same page...

Answer (score 0):

Answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1743630/zend-framework-multiplate-navigation-blocks/2030540#2030540).

> I have had this exact same issue. I just create multiple instances of Zend_Navigation_Container in my controllers for each of the menus I need, pass them to the view and then render them by passing the objects directly to the menu render method. As follows:
>
> In the controller:
>
> ```
> $this->view->menu1 = new Zend_Navigation_Container();
> $this->view->menu2 = new Zend_Navigation_Container();
> ```
>
> In the view:
>
> ```
> $this->navigation()->menu()->renderMenu($this->menu1);
> $this->navigation()->menu()->renderMenu($this->menu2);
> ```
>
> You could even customise each one (by inserting method calls after the initial menu() call:
>
> ```
> $this->navigation()->menu()->setUlClass('my_first_menu')->renderMenu($this->menu1);
> $this->navigation()->menu()->setUlClass('my_second_menu')->renderMenu($this->menu2);
> ```