# Zend navigation object empty in view phtml

Tags: zend-framework, partial, zend-navigation, php

I have a module based application with a default and a user module.
My Navigation menu which is called from the layout is working fine, but now want to create a sidemenu. I would like to call it from the e.g. language.phtml in user/settings/language.

in my language.phtml

```
...
<?php echo $this->navigation()->menu()
    ->setPartial('partials/sidemenu.phtml')
    ->render(); ?>
...
```

This partial is in the scripts directory in the user module.
The partial is being called but for some reason the navigation/container object is empty.

Thanks in advance!

Peter

Comment: Doesn't look like you are passing the container to menu(). Where are you setting it?

Comment: I'm using the same code i use in the layout.

Comment: Perhaps this will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1743630/zend-framework-multiplate-navigation-blocks/2030540#2030540